# verilog component value passing

Tags: module, verilog

I am just beginning to learn verilog. I wrote two programs for that purpose. Here is my first program:

```
 module test1(i,o);
 input i;
 output o;

 wire[0:63] i;
 wire[0:63] o;

 assign o = i * 2.0;
 endmodule

 module test1_tb();
 reg[0:63] inp;
 wire[0:63] outp;
 initial
 begin
 assign inp = 2.0;
 $monitor("input=%f, output=%f",inp,outp);
 end
 test1 t1(inp,outp);
 endmodule
```

This gives me the following result when I run it in ModelSim:

```
 # input=2.000000, output=4.000000
```

Then I edited the above program as follows:

```
module test1(i1,i2,h1,w1,w2,b1);
input i1;
input i2;
input w1;
input w2;
input b1;
output h1;

wire[0:63] i1;
wire[0:63] i2;
wire[0:63] h1;
wire[0:63] w1;
wire[0:63] w2;
wire[0:63] b1;

assign h1 = 1/(1+ 2.718281828459**((-1.0)*(i1 * w1 + i2 * w2 + b1)));
endmodule

 module test1_tb();
 reg[0:63] i1;
 reg[0:63] i2;
 reg[0:63] w1;
 reg[0:63] w2;
 reg[0:63] b1;
 wire[0:63] h1;
 initial
 begin
 assign i1 = 0.05;
 assign i2 = 0.10;
 assign w1 = 0.15;
 assign w2 = 0.20;
 assign b1 = 0.35;
 $monitor("i1=%f, i2=%f, w1=%f, w2=%f, b1=%f, h1=%f",i1,i2,w1,w2,b1,h1);
 end
 test1 n1(i1,i2,h1,w1,w2,b1);
 endmodule
```

For this program I get the output:

```
 # i1=0.000000, i2=0.000000, w1=0.000000, w2=0.000000, b1=0.000000, h1=1.000000
```

It seems the module does not get the initial values in the second program. But all I did was adding few more input lines to the first program and changing the calculation.

Right now I don't know what's the error with this. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type `reg` is not designed to implicitly handle floating point math. As such, real constants assigned to the `reg` variables are rounded to the nearest integer (see IEEE1800-2012 Section 5.7.2, SystemVerilog LRM; sorry I dont have IEEE1364, Verilog LRM, to find the reference in there).

If you simply want to do some floating point math, you can use the `real` type which is the same as a double. Otherwise, if you want to do floating point math in hardware, youll need to deal with the complexities of it yourself (or borrow from an IP core). Also note that Verilog is not a scripting language, but a Hardware Descriptive Language, so unless you are trying to design hardware, you are much better off using Python, Ruby or Perl for general purpose stuff.

Comment: Thank you. I guess I'd stick with real values for now. I am supposed to do a very complex program with Verilog and since I don't have any knowledge of it, I thought I'd start at a very high level. So I'd have to design component by component later.